# How do I get a list of Devise scopes (models) like User, Admin, etc.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I get a list of Devise scopes in a rails (4.2.1) app using devise (3.4.1)?

Something like:

```
> devise_scopes
#=> [User, Admin]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% Devise.mappings.each do |scope| %>
<%= scope[0] %>
<% end %>
```

Additional info on `Devise::Mapping`
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Mapping